# Low-Memory warning with enough empty RAM

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ram

We are reacting on local low-memory warning using this code:

```
 - (void)manageMemoryWarning {
    [[[SPAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:kHinweis message:[WWSError errorTextForCode:WWSErrorSpeicherfastvoll] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Hilfe", nil] show];
}

- (void)start {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(manageMemoryWarning) name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)stop {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:nil];
}
```

While there is 320MB empty RAM space the app is getting such warnings and is presenting the alert to the user. Why are the warnings fired? There is enough empty space.

[image: Warning]

Comment: @HAS the alert is fired by the didReceiveMemoryWarning method.

Answer (score 1):

iOS gives low memory warnings when your app takes what it considers to be too much RAM.

For example, on an iPhone 4, which has 512 MB of RAM, the OS will give you low RAM warnings once your app goes over 256.

Roughly speaking, iOS will pester you if you try to allocate more than half of the device's RAM, regardless of how much RAM is being taken up by other apps.

Comment: But we are using 50MB of the iPads 512MB... this is far under 256.

Comment: I don't know if fragmentation has anything to do with this. Have you shut down and restarted the iPad? (I bet you have) I'm looking around for a tool I once found that let you allocate memory and displayed when the warnings happened...

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I shut down the iPad more than once.... But it doesn't help.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with no luck, iPad Air 2 with 2GB memory getting warnings when my app is using 200MB... No solution yet